# Search first appearence in matrix under time complexity demands

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, time-complexity

I need to write a psuedo code for an algorithm that gets as an input a matrix (n x m) and outputs the row index of the first appearence of 0

I should describe two algorithms which one of them performs in O(mlogn) and the second one performs in O(m+n)

**Special attribute of the matrix :**
The matrix consists only of 0 and 1.
Once a zero value is entered all of the same column below that cell needs to be zero aswell.

Example for valid input:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 1  
1 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The output should be : 1

Edit : I was able to come up with an algorithm with O(mlogn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st algorithm O(m*log(n))**

Inside a column the values are sorted in descending order. This means you can find the first `0` in `O(log(n))` by using a binary-search inside the column.

There are `m` columns to search. This leads to `O(m*log(n))` to search all columns for their first `0`. Finding the first `0` among those `m` results is `O(m)` which is dominated by the `O(m*log(n))` of the previous search.

**2nd algorithm O(m+n)**

The second algorithm start from the cell at `(n,m)`. For each column, starting from the last, we go up while we are on a cell with a `0`. When we hit a `1` we move to the previous column.

```
i <- n
j <- m
r <- (-1, -1)
while (j >= 0):
  if M(i,j) == 1:
    j <- j-1
    continue
  while (i >= 0 && M(i,j) == 0)
    r <- (i,j)
    i <- i-1
```

At the end the result is in `r` or there was no result at all and `r = (-1,-1)`

Comment: If i understand the second algorithm correctly it says something like : 
Start at the bottom right cell.  if the value is 1 skip one cell left  if the value is 0 skip one cell up until im out of bounds.
Was I describing it correctly?

Comment: You go up more than one cell up while there are `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer was for the old question which didn't include the **Special attribute of the matrix**

---

I don't think it's possible to come up with an algorithm that performs better than O(mn) in the worst case.

Here is a naive solution that checks each element of the matrix.

```
def solve(mat, n, m):
   for i in range(1, n):
      for j in range(i, m):
         if mat[i][j] == 0:
            return i

   return -1
```

In the worst case (eg when there are no 0s in the input matrix):

The outer for loop will run n times and for each iteration, the inner for loop will run m times.

So the total time complexity will be O(m * n)

Comment: There is a solution to what im asking (it's part of a Uni assignment).
This doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Does the question mention that each row is sorted? 

If the rows are sorted, we can solve it in O(m*log(n)) and we can further improve it to O(m + n). I can describe this method in detail if you want.

Comment: The matrix is not exactly sorted but it there is one rule, i explained the question poorly, edited the post